# Get Base64 Encoded binary data from file in Apex

Tags: apex, rest-api, files, contentversion, base64

I am trying to generate binary data from files in base64 encoded format in Apex. The purpose is to send that resume data to an external system so that they can parse and send it back.

I was able to achieve it using an aura component. Here is the code for that

JS File

```
    uploadHelper: function(component, event, counter) {
    // start/show the loading spinner   
    component.set("v.showLoadingSpinner", true);
    // get the selected files using aura:id [return array of files]
    var fileInput = component.find("fileId").get("v.files");
    
    // get the first file using array index[0]  
    var file = fileInput[counter];
    var self = this;
    
    if(counter < fileInput.length) {
        // create a FileReader object 
        var objFileReader = new FileReader();
        // set onload function of FileReader object   
        objFileReader.onload = $A.getCallback(function() {
            var fileContents = objFileReader.result;
            var base64 = 'base64,';
            var dataStart = fileContents.indexOf(base64) + base64.length;
            
            fileContents = fileContents.substring(dataStart);
            // call the uploadProcess method 
            self.uploadProcess(component, file, fileContents, counter, fileInput.length);
        });
        objFileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }else{
        component.set("v.showLoadingSpinner", false);
    }    
},
uploadProcess: function(component, file, fileContents, count, totalCount) {
    
    var action = component.get("c.saveTheFile");
    var recordid = component.get("v.recordId");
    
    action.setParams({
        fileName: file.name,
        base64Data: encodeURIComponent(fileContents),
        contentType: file.type,
        PositionId : recordid
    });
    
    // set call back 
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        console.log('state ' + state);
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            
        }// handel the response errors        
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            
        } else if (state === "ERROR") {
            
        }
    });
    // enqueue the action
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}})
```

Apex Class :

```
public static Id saveTheFile(String fileName, String base64Data, String contentType) {
    
base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data, 'UTF-8');
    
//Call out  
doCallOut(base64Data,fileName,contentType,PositionId);

return null;}
```

This is working as expected.

I am trying to achieve the same thing using a batch class that will pick up the files from the library and convert the file body to base64 binary data and sends it to external system. But I am unable to do so. Sometimes, getting a message File is too large when uploading a file of 2 pages only, or the file is corrupted.

Here is my batch class:

```
public class FileProcessorBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,DataBase.AllowsCallouts {

String query = '';

public FileProcessorBatch() {
    //Removed unnecessary code
}

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
    
    ContentVersion conVer = (ContentVersion)scope[0];
    
    String str = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(conVer.VersionData);
    //String data = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(EncodingUtil.base64Decode(str));
    String filename = 'SampleCV.docx';
    
    saveTheFile(filename, data);
}

public void saveTheFile(String fileName, String base64Data) {
    doCallOut(base64Data,fileName);
}

public static void doCallOut(String body,String fileName){
    
    //Get End Point and other credentials from Custom Metadata
    Map<String,String> calloutMap = getCalloutMapping();
    
    SHRPWrapper wrapObj = new SHRPWrapper();
    wrapObj.FileData = body;
    wrapObj.FileName = fileName;
    wrapObj.UserKey = calloutMap.get('User Key');//'';
    wrapObj.Version = calloutMap.get('Version');//'7.0.0';
    wrapObj.SubUserId = calloutMap.get('Sub User Id');
    
    
    System.debug('CPU Now'+Limits.getCpuTime());
    System.debug('calloutMap'+calloutMap);
    HTTP h = new HTTP();
    HTTPRequest r = new HTTPRequest();
    r.setEndpoint(calloutMap.get('End Point'));
    r.setMethod('POST');
    r.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    r.setBody(JSON.serialize(wrapObj));
    r.setTimeout(120000);
    HTTPResponse resp = h.send(r);
    
    System.debug('body'+resp.getStatusCode());
    System.debug('body'+resp.getBody());
    System.debug('CPU Now1'+Limits.getCpuTime());
}

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
}}
```

Please let me know how I can resolve the above issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you found a solution?